# Android how to approach to load data once?

Tags: android, load, contacts, tabwidget

This is a general question in my mind. It might sound silly but I am wondering whether is possible or not.

Basically I have a tabwidget and when the one of the tabs is clicked it retrieves contacts from content provider and put them in a listview. if you have more than 200 contacts this obviously takes about 3 secs to load. here is the question comes in that when the tab is clicked first time it loads the contacts in the listview. and when I change the tab (click another tab) and come back and click the contact tab again it should not spend again 3 seconds to load the data. the list should be already loaded there? This is just my guess and not sure if that can be implemented some how. If you have an idea please share it.

Thank you.

Comment: can u please post a code snipet

Answer (score 1):

User a [CursorLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) to load a cursor for your contacts. The cursor is in memory and unless something changes with the contacts, even if you switch out to a different tab, coming back to the first tab shouldn't require a reload. Also, note that while the CursorLoader wasn't introduced until Api-11, you can still use it via the [Android Support Package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html).